# Best practice of akka actors stopping/killing

Tags: java, akka, actor

What is the best practice regarding actors in the system -

If there is an actor that I know is now longer used and won't receive any messages - should I stop it of is it okay to keep him in the system resource wise?

Comment: `actorRef ! PoisonPill` - it kills all actors created by your actor. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13847963/651140

Comment: There's absolutely no problem in having a lot of actors since they are very lightweight. When I say a lot, I mean even millions. If you really need to kill it, just send appropriate message and use `context.stop(self)` / `context().stop(getSelf());`. I wouldn't use `PoisonPill` since it's... too easy. :)

Comment: @BranislavLazic, there is a problem having a lot of actors, because the actors will not be garbage collected and you may end with a memory leak